# Is possible to create a shell like bash in python, ie: Bash replacement?

Tags: python, bash, shell, replace

I wonder if is possible to create a bash replacement but in python. I have done REPLs before, know about subprocess and that kind of stuff, but wonder how use my python-like-bash replacement in the OSX terminal as if were a native shell environment (with limitations).

Or simply run ipython as is...

P.D. The majority of the google answer are related to create shell *scripts*. I'm interested in create *a shell*..

Comment: You can create a shell in any language .. for all intents and purposes you can do anything in any turing complete language.  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Not even remotely true. The ability to calculate any computable function does not imply or equate being able to interface with a host OS to the degree required to make anything resembling a bash replacement.

Comment: Ok, some what Is the minimun necesary to do for resembling a bash replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible -- check out [hotwire](https://code.google.com/p/hotwire-shell/) for a great example of a shell written in python.

Comment: It was last updated in 2008, also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4750/what-killed-hotwire-shell; it does answer the question though

Comment: So, according to https://code.google.com/p/hotwire-shell/wiki/HotwireVsBinSh, this part: "Second, the default system command display is not a full terminal emulator" mean that is the answer to my question? So for example, ipython can't be a shell because is not a emulator?

Comment: A terminal emulator is a piece of software (like xterm or Konsole) which emulates an old hardware terminal (like the classic VT100). A shell runs _inside_ a terminal emulator, just like bash or zsh or ipython runs inside xterm. When a program is described as a "full terminal emulator", that means that it responds to things like ANSI escape sequences to move the cursor, display color, and so forth. By way of comparison, if you create a GUI program in Qt with a QText widget to display STDOUT and a QLineEdit to read STDIN, you do not have a "full terminal emulator".

Comment: As for "what killed the hotwire shell", I would imagine that it was the combination of "shell + UI" that did it. If they had provided two programs -- one a standard CLI, and one the GUI -- then it might have appealed to more users. Of course, it would have made it difficult to implement most of the features.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. You can simply make an executable Python script, call it `/usr/bin/pysh`, add this filename to `/etc/shells` and then set it as your user's default login shell with `chsh`.

Comment: Well, my question is more in the style what is necessary to recreate to have a proper shell. The task look trivial (ie: like you said) but wonder what features are a MUST to have a shell as bash from the point of view of the OS. Exist something I need to be aware, like respond to some OS command, conform to a spec or something like that?

Comment: From the point of view of the OS, the only MUST is to be executable. From there it's all optional. If you want to use your shell as a script interpretter, it has to accept a filename as the first argument. If you want to run pipelines, you have to open pipes and set up the file descriptors for the commands. If you're asking what's required to be sh compatible, that's an entirely different question.

Answer (score -2):

I don't mean to advertise, but am writing an open source one myself, purely in Python. You can check it out here: [Project Shell](https://github.com/GenericError/Project-Shell)

So **yes**, it definitely is possible, although there may be some performance implications for commands that are written in Python that require lots of number crunching.